# DPRP is disabled for this merchan & how to create recurring account

Tags: api, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Paypal DPRP is disabled for this merchant, i am working with paypal pro using sandbox so far it is working fine with the one time payment but when i change it to recurring,it gives an error of DPRP is disabled for this merchant
any idea how can create recurring payment account in paypal

Answer (score 0):

you need to contact PayPal technical support they could add it for you as it's not added by default. Go to paypal.com/mts,

click --> https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask/session/L3RpbWUvMTQ3MTYxNzg4NC9zaWQvTHdhb3N0WW0%3D

Ask for recurring Payments for Direct Credit Card processing.